# ¿Cómo puedo reproducir una animacion con sonido?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es este:

```
import cocos
from cocos.audio.effect import Effect
from pyglet.image import load, ImageGrid, Animation

class MiCapa(cocos.layer.Layer):
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, buttons, modifiers):
        mi_efecto_sonoro = Effect('explosion.wav')
        mi_efecto_sonoro.sound.set_volume(0.1)
        mi_efecto_sonoro.play()
        mi_secuencia = ImageGrid(load('secuencia_explosion.png'), 4, 4)
        mi_animacion = Animation.from_image_sequence(mi_secuencia, 0.05, False)
        self.mi_sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite(mi_animacion, (x, y))
        self.add(self.mi_sprite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cocos.director.director.init(caption = 'Ejemplo animación y sonido',audio_backend='sdl')
    mi_escena = cocos.scene.Scene(MiCapa())
    mi_efecto_sonoro = Effect('explosion.wav')
    cocos.director.director.run(mi_escena)
```

Es un ejemplo en un libro, el error que manda es:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\GAMEX\Desktop\PYTHON
> LIBRO\Videojuegos_Python\ejemplo_animacion_y_sonido.py", line 22, in
>
> cocos.director.director.init(caption = 'Ejemplo animación y sonido',audio_backend='sdl')   File
> "C:\PYTHON3104\lib\site-packages\cocos\director.py", line 350, in init
> raise NoAudioError(msg) cocos.audio.exceptions.NoAudioError: cocos.audio isn't able to work without needed dependencies. Try
> installing pygame for fixing it, or forcing no audio mode by calling
> director.init with audio=None, or setting the COCOS2D_NOSOUND=1
> variable in your env.

---

Según ya tengo todo instalado (las versiones más recientes) y debería funcionar, pero sigue igual.

¿O tengo que poner la carpeta de actividades donde instalé python?

Comment: De todo lo que instalaste, probaste instalando pygame como indica el error?

Comment: Segun el libro y todo, esta instalado como dice, pero tratando de interpretar el error, dice "COCOS.AUDIO no esta disponible para funcionar sin las dependencias necesarias", segun el libro, cocos se instala en el simbolo del sistema una ves que instalaste PYTHON, con un comando lo instalas, pero creo que va mas a la libreria, ya que el libro tiene informacion del 2018 2019, pudiera ser que la libreria sea diferente y buscando, la informacion  es escaza en internet o yo no se buscar.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces se me ocurre otra posible fuente del problema. Tenes 2 o más versiones de Python instaladas?

Comment: Que yo sepa no ¿Como lo podria checar? segun yo, tengo solamente la version mas reciente 3.10.4

Comment: Mmmm, entonces no se me ocurre como ayudarte... suerte con el problema.

Comment: Ahi puse la captura de lo que tengo instalado, pero gracias.

Comment: te recomendaría que pruebes lo mismo pero con una versión anterior de python, 3,7 ó 3.8 a veces hay incompatibilidades entre las versiones de python y las bibliotecas.